# setting content length header throws unknown error

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

When grabbing text in unity from a webpage it throws this error

```html
Error: Unknown Error
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
<DownloadFile>c__Iterator0:MoveNext() (at Assets/Websharp/Scripts/WebSharp.cs:81)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)
```

This error is thrown from here *Note:* `w = new WWW(urlPath)`

```c#
if (w.error != null) {
            Debug.LogError ("Error: " + w.error);
        }
```

Online php code

```c#
<?
    $scriptText = "";

    $file_handle = fopen("largeFile.cs","r");
    while(!feof($file_handle)){
        $line = fgets($file_handle);
        $scriptText = $scriptText . $line;
    }
    fclose($file_handle);

    $size = strlen($scriptText);

    header("Content-length: " . $size);

    echo $scriptText;
?>
```

After serveral test I eventually learned that if I comment out the two lines `$size = strlen($scriptText);` and `header("Content-length: " . $size);` then the code runs without issue but if i dont comment out these 2 lines it throws the error

What is the root of the issue and how do i fix it?

Edit:

I have found that the root of the issue is in fact `header("Content-length: $size');` if I throw random letters in there like `"Conehsbhdbisb: $size"` the code actually loads so y conclusion is there is something specific about `Content-length` that is causing the issue

Comment: Are you using a paid or free server?

Comment: shared hosting on altervista

Comment: Contact your host and tell them to update your server. The problem is from your server. That script runs fine on mine. I've seen similar issues from others before but they always end up as server setup issues or update issue.